# Varying Max/Min Behaviour for Electronic Blood Pressure Cuffs

Tags: blood, blood-pressure, heart-disease, heart, blood-circulation

Suppose an electronic blood pressure cuff (automated sphygmomanometer) attempts to measure a patient’s blood pressure.  Consider the following scenarios:

1. The blood pressure cuff inflates to a reading of 170mmHg, then deflates to 60mmHg before returning a result of 120/80mmHg.
2. The blood pressure cuff inflates to a reading of 170mmHg, then deflates to 40mmHg before returning a result of 120/80mmHg.
3. The blood pressure cuff inflates to a reading of 140mmHg, then deflates to 60mmHg before returning a result of 120/80mmHg.
4. The blood pressure cuff inflates to a reading of 140mmHg, then deflates to 40mmHg before returning a result of 120/80mmHg.

I’m curious: what are the possible reasons a blood pressure cuff would behave differently in these scenarios, yet still return the same result (120/80mmHg)? Does this different behaviour provide any additional information about blood pressure, heart health or circulation beyond the final reading? Does this different in behaviour ever suggest cause for concern?

Note that if a particular blood pressure cuff has exhibited one of these behaviour (scenario 1-4) then using a blood pressure cuff of a different brand still seems to give the same result. Consequently it seems like this behaviour is not specific to a particular brand.

Comment: An automatic cuff inflates until it determines that it's well above the patient's systolic pressure. To my knowledge, manufacturers don't make their algorithms public, but I would imagine they do it the same way humans do: they listen until they no longer hear a pulse. Why that might vary from time to time is anybody's guess, which makes this a rather speculative question. The [only article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1121444/) I could find says that the newer devices use "fuzzy logic."